# Google API V3 getting js error in google main.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I get js error ( object doesn't manage the remove method and other error) from  google main.js when using the geocode service but my call to geocode service works fine.

The problem is that blocks when navigate because those error occurs on the exécution of this script !

I 'm currently using ten v3.exp version, I try the v3.13 and same errors occurs.

I tried to had a div for a map even if I 'm not using it on this page.

Any ideas woulb be welcome

Thank's in advance
Code looks like this :

```
function SearchGoogle(adress)
{

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


geocoder.geocode({ 'address': adress}, ResponseAnalyse)

return;

}

function ResponseAnalyse(results,status)
{


 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
{


    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < results[i].address_components.length; j++) {

            for (var k = 0; k < results[i].address_components[j].types.length; k++)       {

                if (results[i].address_components[j].types == "postal_code") {
                    var gcp = results[i].address_components[j].short_name;
                }

            }
        }

    }

}                           
}
```

Comment: @davidkonrad:The errors occurs before I call Geocode Google service, It's not a simple html page, I use an aspx which generate an xml flow which is parsed with an xsl and my js script is in a separate file and the generated html is crypted so it's quite difficult to show you the code simply.

Comment: Yes I know the call to the geocode works fine but I got errors in the script console before the call. I have set the call of the V3 api in the head of the HTML, Do I need to set something else in order to use geocode service. It seems that the errors occcurs when loading http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/fr_fr/mapfiles/api-3/14/7/main.js

Comment: Do you know if we need to add a google.maps.event.addDomListener each time we call the google map api service ?

Comment: I know for a fact that you should not :) The addDomListener used in most google examples is to avoid initialize() or whatever to run before the dom and scripts is loaded. After that you create maps on the fly as you wish. But again, it is impossible to guess anything out of your (working) code. I just know, that when you get errors like those you mention above, the map or something associated to it is not initialized properly, or - perhaps - you pass a wrong object to a function. But who could tell? main.js is the core google map library.